# Alert system for game or simulator

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am creating an alert system for a game/sim in C# that keeps track of negative actions performed by the user during a training exercise. There are preconfigured alerts that have data, such as UI text and how many times the alert may be triggered before the user fails the exercise. Whenever an alert is triggered, there may or may not also be data bundled with the alert that I refer to as "alert instance" data, such as the user's speed. I am trying to design the system in the most modular way so new alerts can easily be created and added over time and such that it also allows for quick querying.

I created an abstract class for an alert so I could create one type of alert that does not require instance data and another one that does. I have also created a separate controller class that manages alerts and provides an API.

Below is the code that can run in dotnetfiddle

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample 
{
    public abstract class BaseAlert
    {
        public string ID;
        public string Message;
        public int FailCount;
        
        public int TriggerCount;
    }
    
    // an alert that does not require instance data
    public class Alert : BaseAlert
    {
        public virtual void Trigger()
        {
            TriggerCount += 1;
        }
    }
    
    // an alert that requires data when triggered
    public class BundleAlert : BaseAlert
    {
        public List<AlertData> InstanceData;
        
        public virtual void Trigger(AlertData data)
        {
            if(InstanceData == null)
            {
                InstanceData = new List<AlertData>();
            }
            
            TriggerCount += 1;
            InstanceData.Add(data);
        }
        
        // create a subclass of this to create alert-specific data
        public abstract class AlertData
        {
        }
    }
    
    public class CollisionAlert : BundleAlert
    {
        public override void Trigger(AlertData data)
        {
            if(!(data is CollisionData))
            {
                throw new Exception("CollisionAlert requires CollisionData");
            }
            base.Trigger(data);
        }
        
        public class CollisionData : AlertData
        {
            public float speed;
        }
    }
    
    public class AlertController
    {
        private Dictionary<string, BaseAlert> _alerts;
        
        public AlertController()
        {
            _alerts = new Dictionary<string, BaseAlert>();
        }
        
        // create preconfigured alert
        public void SetupAlert(BaseAlert alert)
        {
            _alerts.Add(alert.ID, alert);
        }
        
        // trigger an alert
        public void Alert(string id, BundleAlert.AlertData data)
        {       
            if( _alerts[id] is BundleAlert )
            {
                ((BundleAlert)_alerts[id]).Trigger(data);
            }
            else
            {
                ((Alert)_alerts[id]).Trigger();
            }
        }
        
        // used to demo querying the alerts
        public void PrintAlerts()
        {
            var keys = _alerts.Keys;
            foreach(var key in keys)
            {
                if(_alerts[key] is CollisionAlert)
                {
                    var speed = ((CollisionAlert.CollisionData)(((CollisionAlert)_alerts[key]).InstanceData[0])).speed;
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Collision at: " + speed);
                }
                else if(_alerts[key] is Alert)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Alert: " + ((Alert)_alerts[key]).ID + "; TriggerCount = " + ((Alert)_alerts[key]).TriggerCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main() 
    {
        AlertController _alertController = new AlertController();
        
        Alert failedToStop = new Alert()
        {
            ID = "FailedToStop",
            Message = "Failed to stop",
            FailCount = 1
        };
        _alertController.SetupAlert(failedToStop);
        
        CollisionAlert collision = new CollisionAlert()
        {
            ID = "WallCollision",
            Message = "Wall Collision",
            FailCount = 1
        };
        _alertController.SetupAlert(collision);
        
        CollisionAlert.CollisionData collisionData = new CollisionAlert.CollisionData()
        {
            speed = 5.0f
        };
        
        _alertController.Alert("FailedToStop", null);
        _alertController.Alert("WallCollision", collisionData);
        
        _alertController.PrintAlerts();
    }
}
```